# C Programming -Linked List Implementation with characters

Tags: c

MY CODE:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
 char data;
 struct node *next;
};

void main()
{   char A;
struct node *head,*ptr;
ptr=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
printf("Enter data for node 1 \n");
scanf("%c",&ptr->data);
head=ptr;
int i=2;
while(1)
{
    ptr->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr=ptr->next;
    printf("\nEnter data for node %d:::\n",i);
    scanf("%c",&ptr->data);
    ptr->next=NULL;
    i=i+1;
    printf("Do you want to continue Y OR N");
    scanf("%c",&A);
    if(A=='Y')
        continue;
    else
        break;

}

struct node *temp;

temp=head;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    printf("%c=>",temp->data);
    temp=temp->next;
}
printf("NULL");





}
```

For this code I can only enter the first character data after that it is skipping the scanf portion within the while loop.
But when I am doing the same code with integer it is giving me the right output.
Here if I replace the same code instead of having characters I replace it by integers it works fine. 
I couldnt find a way to fix it.
Plz help.

Comment: Your problem isn't a linked list but incorrect use of `scanf()`. `%c` consumes a single character **only** and doesn't skip any whitespace (like newline). OTOH, `%d` **does** skip whitespace characters. See also my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: When you end the first input, do you not use the `Enter` key? That key will be put into the input buffer as a newline `'\n'` to be read by the next character input function.

Comment: Thanks a lot now i replaced char with char[N] and used %s instead it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments your problem lies not in the linked list implementation, but in the code lines here.

```
scanf("%c",&ptr->data);    //line number 14

scanf("%c",&ptr->data);    //line number 22

scanf("%c",&A);            //line number 26
```

in all these lines %c consumes the new line character(\n) instead of the users input.

To correct the issue, you can place a whitespace in front of the %c like this,

```
scanf(" %c",&ptr->data);    //line number 14

scanf(" %c",&ptr->data);    //line number 22

scanf(" %c",&A);            //line number 26
```